# How to gain accurate results with Painter's algorithm?

Tags: 3d, algorithm, objects, face

A while ago I asked how to determine when a face is overlapping another. The advice was to use a Z-buffer.

However, I cannot use a Z-buffer in my current project and hence I would like to use the Painter's algorithm. I have no good clue as to when a surface is behind or in front of another, though. I've tried numerous methods but they all fail in edge cases, or they fail even in general cases.

This is a list of sorting methods I've tried so far:

- Distance to midpoint of each face
- Average distance to each vertex of each face
- Average z value of each vertex
- Higest z value of vertices of each face and draw those first
- Lowest z value of vertices of each face and draw those last

The problem is that a face might have a closer distance but is still further away. All these methods seem unreliable.

**Edit:** For example, in the following image the surface with the blue point as midpoint is painted over the surface with the red point as midpoint, because the blue point is closer. However, this is because the surface of the red point is larger and the midpoint is further away. The surface with the red point should be painted over the blue one, because it is **closer**, whilst the midpoint distance says the opposite.

[image]

What exactly is used in the Painter's algorithm to determine the order in which objects should be drawn?

Comment: The [painters algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) is just drawing from back to front.

Comment: @3nixios: Yes, obviously, but in what way can I determine the order of 'back to front'?

Comment: All your objects, triangles or vertices will be a certain distance away from the camera when you start drawing. Implementing the basic algorithm (have you succeded?) would be to determine this distance from the camera for each triangle and draw them in the order furthest to nearest. Once that is done, you need to start looking for intersections and cutting up your triangles, which is a [whole different ball game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newell%27s_algorithm). Why can't you use Z-Buffer already? :P

Comment: @3nixios: You're completely correct, but the problem I'm facing is calculating the distance. As I stated, I've tried several distance methods but they're all not perfect. This order results from midpoint distance sorting: http://i.imgur.com/AcfCm.png.

Comment: Are all your polygons on a regular grid like that? If so there may be grid specific things you can do to improve this.

Comment: @pimvdb Can you put that image in your original question? :) It may help if you provided more information, like a specific example; It could be that your calculations are wrong. I can't quite understand "a face might have a closer distance but is still further away" also. Would it be possible for you to try implementing a Z-buffer?

Comment: I'm drawing 2D shapes with 4 vertexes and I cannot work on a per-pixel basis because it's too slow. I'm not utilizing the best drawing framework, so Z-buffering is not a choice. I'm just calculating the projected 2D points and draw 2D shapes.

Comment: @CiscolPPhone: They're all cubes/cuboids like in the image. They should be able to be animated smoothly though, so they're not always at discrete grid fields.

Comment: This is an excellent question I have not found a good answer yet. Suggesting Painter's algorithm as the solution is insufficient, as it doesn't explain how to achieve it. Then the discussion always starts to talk about the unsolvable cases. What if we could assume that a sorting order always exist without the need for cutting the polygons as in the given example image? How to find out the [dependency graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph) for [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for the faces in such cases?

Comment: @msell The questions specifically asks how to gain accurate results with the painters algorithm. Painters algorithm sorts by the distance of the polygon center to the camera. This is fast and easy to implement, but it's flawed unless you can ensure no edge cases will arise (which will really frequent if you have large polygons and changing perspective eg. rotating scenes). I don't understand why you're putting a bounty on this; if you can ensure there's no need to cut polygons, just sort them with the painter's algorithm?

Comment: @bummzack At least [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) doesn't say anything about the polygon center. The problem is deciding which polygons are in front of which ones, and distance to polygon centers is just one possible sorting criteria. Original poster tried many different ways and couldn't find a generic one even though his example doesn't fall into either of the special cases that needs cutting (cyclic overlapping or piercing polygons).

Comment: @msell Center is the most commonly used sorting criteria. Sure, you can use any other criteria (as the OP did), but that won't fix the flaws in painter's algorithm. You might fix one specific case but get an issue at another location. The OP clearly has problems with polygon overlap (it comes with the perspective). It doesn't have to be a scenario as in the school-books where there are piercing and cyclic overlaps of polygons.. these are the very extreme cases and just there to illustrate the issue properly.

Comment: @bummzack A human could quite easily correctly sort the faces of this and many other cases where a distance to center sorting would fail. I'm looking for an algorithm that could do the same.

Comment: @msell Well, then you should ask this as a separate question. The question here is about the painters algorithm and you're obviously looking for something else. There's also a reason that the painters algorithm isn't used on modern hardware. Using a z-buffer provides accurate z-sorting per-pixel and doesn't suffer from the problems that the painter algorithm does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually the distance of the midpoint of a polygon to the camera is being used for z-sorting. The painter's algorithm cannot be 100% accurate by it's nature. There will always be cases where sorting will fail, no matter what reference point you use.

If you want correct z-sorting with the painter's algorithm, you'll have to slice overlapping polygons into smaller parts (eg. by using a quad-tree) and sort these parts individually. This can become quite heavy on the CPU though..

Found this [Powerpoint file](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs418/fa2012/slides/zbuffer.ppt) that illustrates the issue nicely ([PDF Version](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs418/fa2012/slides/zbuffer.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for that Powerpoint, it helped me solve the problem.

Comment: The link is broken. Can anybody find a copy?

Comment: @Keavon Edited. I found a working link for the file.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases for me it always worked using bsp-trees. Split the scene until you have convex set of polygons in bsp-tree's node and then you can easily sort polygons within the nodes. Note that by sorting polygons from the bsp-tree node it seems like the same problem as you described above, but there is a condition not so obvious - after constructing the bsp-tree all the problematic cases are already solved - in node you should end up with set of polygons from which the convexity test must pass - if you pick a plane from one polygon from this set, the rest of the polygons are all either in front of the plane or behind the plane. Using that info makes sorting easy - the sorting functor takes 2 polygons - check in which half-space is the 1st polygon against the 2nd polygon and also check the placement of camera against the second polygon. The 1st polygon is visually behind the 2nd polygon if:
* side(p1, p2) == infront &&  side(camera, p2) == behind
* side(p1, p2) == behind && side(camera, p2) == infront
There are however certain cases where above condition if called with (p1, p2) tells that p1 is visually behind p2, and if called with (p2, p1), tells that p2 is visually behind p1 - in such cases the order doesn't matter as the polygons don't overlap on screen from the camera.

Note also that the tests for determining the side of camera placement against polygons and traversing of bsp-tree are slightly different when dealing with orthographic and perspective projection.

If you cannot afford splitting of the input polygons, I think you are out of luck.